# Angular 8 - Support Multiple Identity Provider

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, identity

We are currently having an angular 8 application that is having Authentication enabled and we use Custom Login Page. The Identity store is our own in house database. Whenever the user tries to login, we have an Authorize API that checks the credentials and generates the Access Token which will be used for accessing the required API resources.

We have a need to add support for multiple authentication provider (like Azure AD, OKTA). The requirement is to support the current login mechanism as well as support one more provider (could be OKTA or Azure AD).

How can we design the Angular UI and API to support this requirement? Are there any package that support multiple identity provider in Angular? How can we generate the Access Token?

Comment: have you considered leveraging Azure AD for auth? You can support all others from there. Azure AD makes auth easy. For example, you can then use this lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular

Comment: @pixelbits We need to support AAD or OKTA along with the existing login mechanism

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the architecture does not sound right to support what you need.

I would aim for the below 'federated' approach - it requires some investment but you will be in a good place once done:

- Use a standards based authorization server (AS) for your apps - do not build your own token issuing
- When logging in you first redirect to the AS
- The AS presents a screen where an identity provider (IDP) is selected
- The AS redirects to the IDP and the user logs in
- The IDP issues a token and posts it to the AS
- The AS issues a token and posts it to your UI
- Your UIs can post tokens to your Web APIs

This will simplify your code a lot:

- UIs only need to do OAuth redirects against the AS
- APIs only need to validate one type of token
- Much less coding and configuration in UIs and APIs
- Adding a new provider or features such as multi factor only require canges in the AS configuration
- Easy to add new UIs and APIs that follow the same model